# Multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET WebForms without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, post, submit-button

An ASP.NET Repeater results in following HTML code on client side:

```
<form name="sourceForm" method="post" action="sources.aspx" id="sourceForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Best Buy</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Receive data" name="RecData1110" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Walmart</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Receive data" name="RecData1085" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Seven Eleven</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Receive data" name="RecData1125" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The `name` attribute of each button is dynamically generated from text prefix and record ID from database.

How to get information which button has posted the form **without involving JavaScript**? (I know how to do this with JavaScript). It should be done with POST request.

Typically I get values of controls in a following way:

```
Request.Form["ControlName"]
```

But in this case I do not have any idea how determine who posted the form.

Is this possible at all with pure HTML and ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that enumeration should be involved:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        int? id = null;
        foreach (string item in Request.Form.AllKeys)
            if (item.StartsWith("RecData"))
                id = int.Parse(item.Replace("RecData", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a flat file with extension .html and open it up in a browser.  Use this code:

```
<HTML>
<FORM>
<INPUT Type="Submit" ID="Button1" Name="Button1_Was_Pressed" Value="Click Me">
<INPUT Type="Submit" ID="Button2" Name="Button2_Was_Pressed" Value="Click Me">
</FORM>
</HTML>
```

When you open it up in the browser, you should see two buttons with the caption "Click Me".  So the buttons look identical to the end user.  However, if you click button1, you'll get a query string of

```
?Button1_Was_Pressed=Click+Me
```

And if you click button2, you'll get a query string of

```
?Button2_Was_Pressed=Click+Me
```

Given this behavior, you ought to be able to modify the repeater code to emit a unique Name attribute for each row, and, when the form is submitted, the server can look for the name in the Request.QueryString collection.

```
if (Request.QueryString["Button1_Was_Pressed"] != null) HandleButton1Click();
```

And of course it works with POST too.

```
<HTML>
<FORM method="POST">
<INPUT Type="Submit" ID="Button1" Name="Button1_Was_Pressed" Value="Click Me">
<INPUT Type="Submit" ID="Button2" Name="Button2_Was_Pressed" Value="Click Me">
</FORM>
</HTML>
```

and

```
if (Request.Form["Button1_Was_Pressed"] != null) HandleButton1Click();
```

If you have a ton of buttons, you can loop through them:

```
for (int i=0; i < buttonCount; i++)
{
    string buttonName = String.Format("Button{0}_Was_Pressed", i);
    if (Request.Form[buttonName] != null) HandleButtonClick(i);
}
```

Or you can enumerate the values (using `Allkeys`) just as you have done in your own answer.